# Pull back of the associated sheaf of Rees algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring. Let $I\subset A$ be an ideal. Set B=$\oplus_{n\ge 0}I^n$ to be the Rees algebra associated to $I$, $\widetilde B$ to be the associated sheaf of $B$ on $\operatorname{Spec} A$. Let $f:X\to \operatorname{Spec} A$ be a proper morphism.

**Definition.** For a quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal F$on $X$, define $I^n\mathcal F=\operatorname{Im}(f^*I^n\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal F\to \mathcal F)$.

In [this Stacks tag](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O7) the authors write $f^*\widetilde B=\oplus_{n\ge 0}I^n\mathcal O_X$ without any explanation:

[image]

Suppose $\operatorname{Spec} C\subset X$ is an open affine subset, the section of $f^*\widetilde B$ over $\operatorname{Spec} C$ is $\oplus_{n\ge0} C\otimes_A I^n$, and with $f^*\widetilde B$ identifying to $\oplus_{n\ge 0}I^n\mathcal O_X$ we have $\oplus_{n\ge0} C\otimes_A I^n=\operatorname{Im}(\oplus _{n\ge 0}C\otimes_AI^n\to C)$, but this doesn't look correct. Anyone can help?

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$: this produces better spacing, and I've made the upgrade in your post this time. Do also note that [pictures of text are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) on this network - please consider replacing your images with text.

Comment: @ KReiser thank you to point it out,I have made some edits.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$\oplus_{n\ge0} C\otimes_A I^n=\oplus _{n\ge 0}\operatorname{Im}(C\otimes_AI^n\to C)$ rather than
$\operatorname{Im}(\oplus _{n\ge 0}C\otimes_AI^n\to C)$. The latter makes little sense.

In the definition of a [Rees algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rees_algebra), the direct sum symbol are considered as an [external direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Internal_and_external_direct_sums) so as to make the resulting direct sum a graded ring.

The notation $\operatorname{Im}(C\otimes_AI^n\to C)$ is nothing but the ideal of $C$ generated by the image of $I^n$ via the obvious map $A\to C$. The latter coincides with $C\otimes_A I^n$, as predicted.